# Smooth cell in a CW complex

Tags: smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes

Suppose a $k$-cell in a CW complex is given a smooth structure, so that it is also a smooth $k$-manifold. Is that cell diffeomorphic to the open $k$-ball?

Comment: Being a smooth manifold is a structure, not a property; you need to specify a smooth structure on a topological manifold (this is a property) and nothing in the definition of a CW complex offers such a thing.

Comment: It assumed here that a smooth structure is given to the cell. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: From where? Then of course the answer depends on which smooth structure was given, because there are exotic smooth structures on the open $k$-ball when $k = 4$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4

Comment: The exotic R4 answers the question of whether a smooth k-cell in isolation (i.e. a topological space homeomorphic to a $k$-ball and with smooth structure) is diffeomorphic to a ball (no).  What still remains unclear is whether being a part of a CW complex could force a diffeomorphism. Essentially the question is whether it is possible to extend the exotic smooth manifold to a smooth manifold with boundary where the boundary consists of the cell's boundary-cells.

Comment: The exotic R4 page mentions that any smooth n-manifold which is homeomorphic to an n-ball is also diffeomorphic to an n-ball for $n \neq 4$. Therefore, it is possible that a small constraint such as being part of a CW-complex could remove the exception also for $n = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on $k$...in a CW complex a (open/closed) cell is only *homeomorphic* to a open/closed ball; you can have different differentiable structures on a manifold that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic in some dimensions $\geq 4$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere for a "famous" example).

Comment: Yes, I know the exotic sphere. But I was hoping that because the $k$-cell is part of a CW-complex, that would help to rule out such problems.

Comment: I don't think so, because there is no particular restriction on the homeomorphisms that "define" the cells in the definition of a CW-complex. Even more, you can give a CW-complex structure to an exotic sphere by taking a cell of the right dimension and the right homeomorphism.

Comment: Each homeomorphism must extend in a continuous manner to the boundary cells, so that restricts them somewhat, right? The exotic sphere is homeomorphic to a sphere, and not a ball, so while it works as a cautionary tale, it does not seem to provide a counter-example.

Comment: Maybe you're right, because it seems problematic defining the homeomorphism only on the interior part of $D^n$.

Comment: Each (open) $k$-cell is by definition homeomorphic to an open $k$-ball. But what do you mean by the statement that a cell is a smooth $k$-manifold? Of course it can always be given a smooth structure, but I do not see any connection to the concept of CW-complex. Or do you mean a closed cell which can be given the structure of a smooth $k$-manifold with boundary? Also in that case it is a question about manifolds and not a question about CW-complexes.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to be able to make sense of orientation on a cell; to say that a cell in a CW complex can be oriented in two different ways. For that, I was thinking of adding a smooth structure to a cell so I get access to tangent vectors. I could just state the each cell must be diffeomorphic to a ball. However, I was wondering whether it is equivalent to require each cell to be a smooth manifold.

Comment: @kaba: you don't need a smooth structure to make sense of orientations. An orientation on a (topological) $k$-ball $B$ is a choice of generator of the relative homology $H_n(B, \partial B)$.

Comment: (This is an excellent example of why you should just ask about the thing you actually want to know, rather than reducing your question in a possibly unproductive way to another question and asking that one. Someone showed me a term for this recently but I've forgotten it.)

Comment: getting off topic, @QiaochuYuan perhaps the term is the "XY problem"

Comment: I'm also interested in the question as stated itself.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Anyway thanks for the tip on the orientations!